# Change colours of tools in GIMP 2.10

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to change to colours of the tool buttons in GIMP 2.10? I'm not keen on the grey buttons that do not contrast well with the gre background. I want to make them black so I can actually see them without squinting.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please go to **Edit > Preferences > Interface**

Check your *Icon Theme* as shown in the screenshot below.

You may change your *Theme* for your needs too.

[image]